# Smack Connection to Server Failure

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I setup an *ejabberd* server on my Macbook successfully, and tested it with iChat and Adium. I am trying to setup a Jabberd/XMPP client to work on the Android OS. The following code throws an exception on the `connection.connect()` method:

```
public void login(String username, String password) throws XMPPException {
    ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("my-ejabberd-server-macbook.local", 5222);
    connection = new XMPPConnection(config);

    XMPPConnection.DEBUG_ENABLED = true;
    SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);
    connection.connect();
    connection.login(username, password);
}
```

The following exception was created on the `connection.connect()` method call:

```
XMPPError connecting to my-ejabberd-server-macbook.local:5222.: remote-server-error(502) XMPPError connecting to my-ejabberd-server-macbook.local:5222.
  -- caused by: java.net.SocketException: Host is unresolved: my-ejabberd-server-macbook.local
```

I have the only following permission in the Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue . I am facing the same.

Answer (score 1):

Names under `.local` are resolved by [multicast DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_configuration_networking), and not all software can handle that.  While testing locally, you could add an entry for it to [your `/etc/hosts` file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29).